# Kohana routing. ID that can contain letters but must end with digit

Tags: php, kohana

I want this routes to work

```
forum/forum-name.9 -> controller = forum, action = index, id = forum-name.9
forum/forum-name.9/edit -> controller = forum, action = edit, id = forum-name.9
forum/rules -> controller = forum, action = rules, id = null
```

I tried

```
Route::set('default', '(/<controller>)((/<id>)(/<action>)))', 
 array(
    'controller' => '[a-zA-Z_-]+',
    'action' => '[a-zA-Z_-]+',
   'id' => '[a-zA-Zа-я0-9.-]+',
))
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'forum',
    'action' => 'index',
    'id'=>null
));
```

But its wrong, because id now can contain only letter

Answer (score 2):

Routes should be specific. Do NOT try to sole everything using one route. These will do what you want.

```
Route::set('forum/rules', 'forum/rules')
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'forum',
    'action' => 'rules',
));

Route::set('forum', 'forum/(<name>.)<id>(/<action>)',
 array(
    'action' => 'edit', // the action must not be present (and default to 'index') or be 'edit'
    'name' => '\w+',
   'id' => '\d+',
))
->defaults(array(
    'controller' => 'forum',
));
```

Also, only add `-` to the regex for actions and controllers if you overload something and have it replaced. PHP class and function/method names are not allowed to contain a dash.

Comment: Forget about KISS. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is actually more in line with the KISS principle the more URI schemes you have. Trying to stuff everything in as few routes makes them more complex and harder to maintain. More simple routes is way better. Which covers the first S of KISS I believe :p

Answer (score 0):

This solved my problem

```
'id' => '(\w+.)?\d+'
```